# Convolution of functions defined on manifold

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with fixed volume form $\mu$. How to define a convolution of two 'functions' $f,g \in L^1(M)$? I will be grateful for an answer or for giving me some refrence where it is done in detail. In particular I'm also interested in properties of such convolution

Comment: I doubt you can define convolution without some group structure on the manifold.

Comment: And how about if we assume that the supports of two such functions are sufficiently small?

Comment: As Olivier mentioned if you assume $M$ has a group structure and the measure induced by $\mu$ is a Haar measure then you can define the convolution of compactly supported functions by $f \star g(x) = \int_{M} f(xy^{-1})g(y) d\mu (y).$ if $M$ is compact then obviously all functions on it are compactly supported.

Comment: I don't want my manifold to have group structure. By sufficiently small support I mean that the support is contained in the domain of some chart.